# bootstrap - can i completely replace my old css files with bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

is it possible to completely remove all my old styles and add only bootstrap css classes ? Or I have to add things like position, width etc .

Comment: What do you think what the bootstrap is? A magic box that you open and it knows by itself how exactly you want your page layouted and styled in every detail? For sure you need to modify the css

Comment: @sven-bieder 's  comment may be little bit offensive, but it is true. you (@user1767962) can use bootstrap to support your CSS, you can use their property and modify it as per your requirement in your own stylesheet.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to add your CSS code, but less than without bootstrap because it provides many prototypes of HTML controls, styles, UX,..